# It seems that period.to_timestamp() and asfreq("D") have different behaviours, converting a monthly period to first vs last day of month. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

This might seem like a pedantic question, but that's not its spirit. Consider the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
period=pd.Period("2020-03-15","M") #This object ignores the specific day
print(period.asfreq("D")) #converts to last of month
print(period.to_timestamp()) #converts to first of month
```

This prints 2020-03-31 and then 2017-03-01 00:00:00. Why the different behaviours? The reason I'd ask such a question is because Pandas seems to make particular choices for particular reasons, so perhaps the reason carries some specific or conceptual understanding of the difference between timestamp and period in Pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter `how` in [`Period.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.to_timestamp.html) for last day of month:

```
period=pd.Period("2020-03-15","M") #This object ignores the specific day
print(period.asfreq("D")) #converts to last of month
2020-03-31

print(period.to_timestamp(how='E')) #converts to last of month
2020-03-31 23:59:59.999999999
```

If need remove times, it means set to `00:00:00` use [`Timestamp.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.normalize.html):

```
print(period.to_timestamp(how='E').normalize())
2020-03-31 00:00:00
```

Reason of difference is different default parameter in [`Period.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.asfreq.html) and [`Period.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.to_timestamp.html):

```
print(period.asfreq("D", how='E')) 
2020-03-31

#default 'E' (end)
print(period.asfreq("D")) 
2020-03-31
```

---

```
print(period.to_timestamp(how='S').normalize()) 
2020-03-01 00:00:00

#default 'S' (start)
print(period.to_timestamp().normalize()) 
2020-03-01 00:00:00
```